# SQL function to modify column values

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am using Oracle 10g Database and want to modify column value using sql query.

Account represents a column in table.

```
Account

emp/class/digicat
emp/class/abc
```

I want a sql query which returns column value in below format:

```
Account

@emp/@class/@digicat
@emp/@class/@abc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a single `@` first. Then replace all `/` with `/@`.

```
select '@' || replace(Account, '/', '/@') from tablename
```

Or do you mean replace table contents? Do a similar UPDATE:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Account = '@' || replace(Account, '/', '/@')
```

Comment: Thanks @jarlh for the quick answer !